# Vue 3 Composition API Composable and store action

Tags: vuejs3, composable

Ive just finished making my first composable in Vue 3 and it is working as expected. Now I've run into the problem of how and where to do my store action in the component.

Let me explain some more. My app interface has 2 bootstrap collapse cards, one above another. The first one contains a table of items and the second card is the edit or add item card. The second card is hidden on init and shown when clicking on edit or add new button.

So you click on an item, the top card collapses (closes) and the second card appears already open.

I have this type of interface on all my pages in my app. So instead of creating all this open/close collapsing logic in all of my components, I figured it's best to create a composable.

That is all working nicely. The composable just expects the id of the panel in the top card.

But now, I run into the problem that I don't know how and where to put the store action in the components (update or save).

So this was the situation before:

**component:**

```
<Button content="Save" variant="btn-primary" @click="isSaveClicked" />

<script setup>
// addItem is to add the item ie. save it
function isSaveClicked(){
addItem(newItem.value, newItemPlotNumber.value)
}
</script>
```

**store:**

```
   async addItem(name, plotNumberEnabled) {
      this.isLoading = true

      return apiClient etc etc
    },
```

This was all working fine.

Now, I have added the **composable** in collapse.js:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { Collapse } from 'bootstrap'

export function useCollapse(id) {
  const showEdit = ref(false)
  const showAdd = ref(false)
  const isEditClicked = () => {
    showEdit.value = !showEdit.value
    panelState()
  }
  const isAddClicked = () => {
    showAdd.value = !showAdd.value
    panelState()
  }

  const isSaveClicked = () => {
    panelState()
    showAdd.value = false
  }

  function panelState(){
    let collapsePanel = document.querySelector(id)
    new Collapse(collapsePanel, {
      toggle: true
    })
  }


  return { showEdit, showAdd, isEditClicked, isAddClicked, isSaveClicked }

}
```

And my component now looks like this:

```
const { showEdit, showAdd, isAddClicked, isEditClicked, isSaveClicked } = useCollapse('#libraryPanel')
```

But how do I now add the store action to this button?

I tried this:

```
<Button content="Save" variant="btn-primary" @click="isSaved" />

const { showEdit, showAdd, isAddClicked, isEditClicked, isSaveClicked } = useCollapse('#libraryPanel');

function isSaved(){ 
isSaveClicked(); 
addItem(newItem.value, newItemPlotNumber.value); 
}
```

But thats not working. I am kind of stuck now..

Comment: A nitpick, but using `onX` is far better than `isX` for event handlers. `isX` functions are almost exclusively used to get the state of something.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happened? What did you expect? What differed from what you expected?

Comment: Thanks for answering, will get back on it asap!

Comment: Sorry, "it isnt working" was not really clear. I got a console error that newItem and newItemPlotNumber wasnt being given from the child to the parent correctly. Now I have fixed that and everything works. But is this the way to go? Is this the correct Vue3 way?

Comment: If it is _working_, then your original question is answered (I believe). You can post an answer saying what you did to fix it, and mark it as accepted. As to best practices, etc., [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) is probably a better place to ask (and link to it from here).